# kotlin serialization of array

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization

I am trying to serialise a fixed-size array of a data class into a JSON string, and then decode it back into an array, the problem is I can't seem to find the correct way to deserialize it into an array object

```kotlin
object LisStyles {

    @Serializable
    data class LisStyle(

        var priority: Int = 0,
        var backgroundColor: Int = Color.LTGRAY

    }
    
    var event = Array(MAX_ITEM_COUNT) { LisStyle() }
    
    fun serialiseData(){

        val output = Json.encodeToString(event)

        //The following line causes an exception
        event = Array(MAX_ITEM_COUNT) { Json.decodeFromString<LisStyle>(output) }

    }
}
```

A call to serialiseData() encodes the array correctly but gives a

JSON exception: Expected start of the object '{', but had 'EOF' instead

Can anyone suggest how to do this correctly?

Many thanks

Comment: Post your complete json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `event = Json.decodeFromString<Array<LisStyle>>(output)` instead